# Simplifying Python List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic, list-comprehension

Can someone simplify the logic behind this piece of code:

```
scores=[(similarity(prefs,person,other),other)
for other in prefs if other!=person ]
```

I tried implementing it like this

```
for others in prefs:
    if others!=person:
        scores=[similarity(prefs,person, others),others]
```

But it only picks the last element of others.
Btw prefs is a 2D dictionary and scores is supposed to be a list of tuples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the same as making repeated *appends* of the tuples to a list:

```
scores = []
for others in prefs:
    if others!=person:
        scores.append((similarity(prefs, person, others), others))
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks a lot. It works fine. I wonder why two parenthesis being applied here make a difference. When I try it with one pair of parenthesis for the append function, it gives me a TypeError.

Comment: @ShonAufdaded The parens groups the return value of the function call and `others` as a tuple, otherwise, the expression could be deemed ambiguous.